# Obtaining oscillatory solution and corresponding normal form of DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the constant coefficients DE $$y''+by'+cy=0, \quad  x \in \mathbb{R}$$
a) Use the usual approach to obtain the condition so that its solutions are oscillatory.

b) Find the corresponding normal form DE and derive the same condition from it.

I am having trouble understanding the question because I don't know what they mean by an oscillatory solution. And for b) what do they mean by "normal" form of DE? Do they just mean the equation given?

Comment: Oscillatory usually means wave-like (sine, cosine, etc)

Comment: You might want to consider the eigenvalues for this equation. Hint : the DE has similar structure to quadratic equations

Answer (score 0):

For a), as mentioned in the comments, you need to find criteria for $b$ and $c$ such that the solution has $\sin$ and/or $\cos$ in it. We know that we get a solution on the form $$y = e^{\mu x}(A\cos\lambda x + B\sin\lambda x)$$ if the roots of the characteristic polynomial are complex $r = \mu \pm \lambda i$. In your case, the characteristic polynomial is $$r^2 + br + c = 0$$ see if you can find the criteria for $b, c$ that ensures that the roots are complex.

For b), *normal form* just means solving for the highest derivative, that is write your differential equation on the form
$$\frac{d^n f}{dx^n} = F(f, f' , f'', \ldots, f^{(n-1)}).$$